# Strange behaviour in EXTJS Grid Grouping Expand row - missing CSS?

Tags: extjs, grid

If I look at the grid grouping example at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping.html I can see the rows with a little +/- expand/collapse icons to the left of each grouped row.  If I "inspect element" from my browser on those icons it takes me to the x-grid-group-title::before style

[image]

In my app (which is a Sencha Cmd generated app based on the admin-dashboard template), if I paste the same grid code into one of my pages I don't see the little +/- expand/collapse icons to the left of each grouped row.  If I "inspect element" on the grouped row, there is no ::before CSS.
[image]

Is this because of some strange theme/CSS that's been applied to the admin-dashboard template?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a "sencha app build" and now the +/- expander icons are there.  I assumed a "sencha app refresh" would be sufficient but I guess not